# Calculating new satellite position given pseudorange measurements

Tags: gps, references, satellite, position

I'm looking for a reference/text for an explicit formula to calculate a satellite position given pseudorange measurements from later epoch times. I've seen a lot of matlab code on the internet but I was hoping to have these formulas laid out nicely.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: An explicit formula (i.e. a closed form solution) isn't common because the formula isn't linear. Usually you take partial derivatives around a point estimate, and iterate until the residual is acceptable. Hence matlab...

Answer (score 5):

Algebraic solutions are not very common for GPS, however, several do exist. The most well-known one is probably [Bancroft's](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4104017). Others are [Abel's](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/165379) and [Kleusberg's](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303231747/http://www.uni-stuttgart.de/gi/research/schriftenreihe/quo_vadis/pdf/kleusberg.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

If you look for some libraries and test environment in [c++](https://github.com/swift-nav/libswiftnav) or [python](https://github.com/swift-nav/gnss-analysis) you could have a look at the piksi swift software tools. It is open source (LGPL) and the code is well documented in terms of function description + literature sources.

The source code documentation of the function `gnss_analysis/solution.py/singe_point_position` addresses the literature 
Kaplan, E.. Understanding GPS - Principles and applications. 2nd edition Section 2.4.2 for example and implements the procedure.

```
def single_point_position(obs, max_iterations=15, tol=1e-4):
  """
  Computes the single point position by iteratively solving linearized
  least squares solutions

  Parameters
  ----------
  obs : pd.DataFrame
      A DataFrame that holds `pseudorange` observations (corrected for satellite
    clock errors), satellite position (`sat_x`, `sat_y`, `sat_z`) all in ECEF
    coordinates at the time of transmission and `tow` variable which corresponds
    to the time of arrival.
      All observations are assumed to have been propagated to a common time of
    arrival.
  max_iterations : int (optional)
      The maximum number of iterations, defaults to 15.
  tol : float (optional)
      Tolerance for convergence (same is used for both position and time),
      defaults to 1e-4.
  Returns
  --------
  spp : dict
    A dictionary holding the single point position.  Keys included:
      pos_ecef : a length three array representing the position in ECEF coords.
      time : the gps system time at the solution
      clock_offset : the receiver clock error
      converged : a boolean indicating convergence.

  Reference:
    Kaplan, E.. Understanding GPS - Principles and applications. 2nd edition Section 2.4.2
  """
  ....
```